# How does MMU find out what address it should translate?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, intel

When we try to read/write some data to/from a specific address we must know where the first page directory is stored and the address we want translate.

As for the first page directory (as far as I know linux uses 4-level paging, so the first one should be `PGD`), and for Intel - `CR3` register will contain the address of PGD, but where the virtual address is stored? How will MMU understand that it should translate exactly this or that address?

***UPD***: I think I should clarify my question and provide a few details how I see that:

As I understood, when some virtual address's gonna be translated we have next steps:

1. Check the TLB.
2. If TLB hits then we have physical address (PA)
3. If it does not, we have to process *translation fault*
4. During translation fault we have to walk through *software page tables* to find the PA.
5. Here have to switch to kernel mode. ***(Btw, I know that usually kernel page tables and user page tables are the same, the difference is only in privileges, so is there a way that we won't switch to kernel mode?)***
6. Then we're gonna set *CR3* register to PGD address (or another top level page directory)
7. ***Now that's our work to walk through this table or not? If software should do it on its own then we know that VA (Virtual Address) within some var and can look for PA in page tables??? Or this work on MMU (or like smth that) and it will go through these tables and as for CR3 will know where the PGD, but how it can understand what address this is translating? Is it in some register or already loaded somewhere in memory?***

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is covered in some depth at https://sxia.medium.com/how-exactly-does-a-mmu-translate-a-virtual-address-to-a-physical-address-cda65a764eb2 and https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Management_Unit

Comment: "When we try… we must know…" Errrr ? It certainly depends **how** you are accessing **what** (since common methods are designed to abstract all that knowledge) Do you mean you are accessing the memory via /dev/mem ?

Comment: @MC68020, not really, I meant that within paged address translation process in order to translate virtual address into physical one we find the address of PGD (which is in CR3) then looking for entry there (usually index is 9 bits of the virtual address) and the same for PUD, PMD, etc. But according to this translation we know where the PGD is stored (CR3), but where the virtual address is stored for now, that we want to translate into physical?

Comment: Then you actually mean "When **the cpu**  tries to read/write…" In other words irrespective of whatever program / driver used to actually read or write ? BTW linux also supports 5-level paging https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/5level-paging.html

Comment: And if I then correctly understand your question then the mmu knows how it should remap thanks to the virtual memory map https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you’ve listed aren’t quite right; hopefully fixing that will allow you to understand what’s going on.

0. The CPU attempts to access memory (*e.g.* to read an instruction, or because the current instruction accesses memory) — this is where the virtual address comes from.
1. Check the TLB.
2. If the TLB has an entry for the virtual address, we’ve got the corresponding physical address.
3. Otherwise, the MMU has to handle the TLB miss (it’s not a fault on x86; it gets counted but the kernel isn’t aware of it).
4. The MMU walks through the pages tables, potentially starting at the value stored in `CR3`. It knows the virtual address it needs to resolve, from step 0.
5. There’s no switch to kernel mode, this is all handled by the MMU (on x86).
6. `CR3` and the page tables had to be set up before the memory access, nothing is changed here. (See [this in-depth analysis of pagewalk coherence](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2015/08/pagewalk-coherence/).)

Some architectures (MIPS, I think) *do* involve the kernel when handling a TLB miss; in such cases the virtual address which needs to be handled is provided in the fault information.

Comment: **3.** Is this not what is named "translation fault" ? Hence, triggering **the cpu**  to start walking tables from a specific address in RAM (CR3) ? (on x86) therefore **4.** I am not sure the MMU is the right subject for the verb and **5** even less sure.

Comment: Great answer, but under "translation fault" I meant TLB miss not page fault, so I'm still thinking this term is correct here. And as I understand MMU always keep an eye on any VA, so when the cpu tries to access any VA, MMU will handle this try and translate the address if it is not in TLB, right? And how MMU will do that is implementation specific things?

Comment: @MC68020 3. a fault means the operating system is involved (see page fault for example); that’s not the case here. 4. At a high level, as far as the rest of the CPU is concerned, the MMU takes care of the page walk; the page walk is transparent to everything else (apart from the added delay), unless the page walk itself causes a page fault (as can happen on Windows for example).

Of course since all x86 CPUs have a built-in MMU now, the distinction is somewhat tenuous (which I suspect is why most texts talk about the CPU walking the page tables).

Comment: @k1r1t0 as above, a fault means the operating system is involved, which isn’t the case here. The MMU doesn’t really “keep an eye” on any VA; it’s invoked explicitly on any CPU-based memory access. It does more than VA-to-PA translation, it also checks permissions, page presence etc.

Comment: @StephenKitt, could you share some link where I can find more details about MMU?

Comment: @k1r1t0 have you read [the Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)?

Comment: @StephenKitt, I've seen this article, and as for me there's no details or smth like you've mentioned (this checks permissions, page presence, etc, and nothing's said about some algorithms that MMU may use, I know this is implementation specific thing, but it'd be useful)

Comment: Right in the introduction: “An MMU effectively performs virtual memory management, handling at the same time memory protection, cache control, bus arbitration and, in simpler computer architectures (especially 8-bit systems), bank switching.” The last two paragraphs in the “Page table entries” go into a little more detail about permissions and page presence. The details of the algorithms are indeed implementation-specific, but the “Examples” section gives a high-level overview and there are links to references in the “References” section.

Comment: The [Intel SDM](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) describes how to set up the MMU on x86 CPUs in detail, but it doesn’t cover the internals. I’m not aware of a really good web site about MMU internals; if you have access to Hennessy & Patterson’s Computer Architecture, a Quantitative Approach, that’s a really good resource, and [Appendix L](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0006/795732/Hennessy_References_Appendices_V1.zip) covers address translation in great detail.